# Java Inheritance - Hibernate6 + JPA - How to prevent selecting all child tables when joining on parent?

Tags: postgresql, java, hibernate

I'm working on a Java application that uses Hibernate6 + JPA.

I have classes like

```
class Thing {
    
    Parent parent

}
```

```
class Parent {
   
}
```

```
class ChildA extends Parent {
    
}
```

```
class ChildB extends Parent {

}
```

I want to be able to write a query like `SELECT * FROM Thing JOIN Parent JOIN ChildA` but NOT select any data from ChildB.

I've tried making the parent table use TABLE_PER_CLASS and JOINED inheritance strategies, and write a HQL query like:

```
SELECT t FROM Thing t
JOIN t.parent p
WHERE
    TYPE(p) = ChildA
```

but this still selects all the child data from ChildA and ChildB, ie:  `SELECT * FROM Thing Join Parent Join ChildA Join ChildB`...

I could implement a Java Model that uses composition instead, but my situation highly favors inheritance, as it requires many less cascading changes in the code base.

Is there a model and combination of annotations to get Hibernate + JPA to produce the desired query?